# How to properly read errors from golang oauth2

Tags: go, oauth, oauth-2.0, godoc

```
token, err := googleOauthConfig.Exchange(context.Background(), code)
if err != nil {
 fmt.Fprintf(w, "Err: %+v", err)
}
```

The output of the fprintf is:

```
Err: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {"error":"code_already_used","error_description":"code_already_used"}
```

I want to check if "error" = "code_already_used". For the life of me, I can't sort out how.

**How do I check/return/read "error" or "error_description" of err?**

I've looked at the oauth2 code and it's a bit above me.

```
// retrieveToken takes a *Config and uses that to retrieve an *internal.Token.
// This token is then mapped from *internal.Token into an *oauth2.Token which is returned along
// with an error..
func retrieveToken(ctx context.Context, c *Config, v url.Values) (*Token, error) {
    tk, err := internal.RetrieveToken(ctx, c.ClientID, c.ClientSecret, c.Endpoint.TokenURL, v)
    if err != nil {
        if rErr, ok := err.(*internal.RetrieveError); ok {
            return nil, (*RetrieveError)(rErr)
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    return tokenFromInternal(tk), nil
}
```

How guess I'm trying to see the (*RetrieveError) part. Right?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
(*RetrieveError)(rErr)
```

converts the`rErr`'s type from `*internal.RetrieveError` to `*RetrieveError`. And since `RetrieveError` is declared in the `oauth2` package, you can *type assert* the error you receive to [`*oauth2.RetrieveError`](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/80673b4a4bfc6c2c58a0b44cf9106913fe293994/token.go#L169) to get the details. The details are contained in that type's Body field as a slice of bytes.

Since a slice of bytes is not the best format to be inspected and in your case it seems like the bytes contain a json object you can make your life easier by predefining a type into which you can unmarshal those details.

That is:

```
type ErrorDetails struct {
    Error            string `json:"error"`
    ErrorDescription string `json:"error_description"`
}

token, err := googleOauthConfig.Exchange(context.Background(), code)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Err: %+v", err)

    if rErr, ok := err.(*oauth2.RetrieveError); ok {
        details := new(ErrorDetails)
        if err := json.Unmarshal(rErr.Body, details); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(details.Error, details.ErrorDescription)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this.

```
arr := strings.Split(err.Error(), "\n")
        str := strings.Replace(arr[1], "Response: ", "", 1)
        var details ErrorDetails
        var json = jsoniter.ConfigCompatibleWithStandardLibrary

        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &details)
        if err == nil {
            beego.Debug(details.Error)
            beego.Debug(details.ErrorDescription)
        }
```